# Efficiently calculate co-occurence matrix

Tags: python, performance

I have a large dataframe (5 rows x 92,579 columns) in the following format:

```
    1  2  3  4  5   6  7  8  9  10  11  ...  92569  92570  92571  92572  92573  92574  92575  92576  92577  92578  92579
0  10  9  8  5  5  10  1  1  6   2   3  ...      9      1      8      3      2      5      5      5      2      2      8
1   3  1  7  4  4   3  8  8  3   6   7  ...      1      8      7      5      6      4      4      4      2      6      7
2   6  4  2  9  7   6  5  5  6   7   2  ...      4      5      2      6      6      9      5      9      3     10      2
3   3  8  4  4  7   3  1  1  3   7   6  ...      8      1      5      7      2      4      1      4      6     10      2
4   4  6  5  5  5   4  1  1  4   8  10  ...      6      1      7      3      6      5      5      5      8      2      9
```

Each of the entries ranges from 1 to 10 (representing an assignment to one of 10 clusters).

I want to create a 92579 x 92579 matrix that represents how many times (ie. in how many rows) the variables in columns *i* and *j* have the same value. For example, variables 4 and 5 have the same value in 3 rows, so entries i_{4,5} and i_{5,4} of the co-occurrence matrix should be 3.
I only need the upper triangular portion of the desired matrix (since it will be symmetric).

I've looked at similar questions here, but they don't address both of these issues:

- How to do this efficiently for a very large matrix
- How to do this for non-binary entries

Comment: The resulting matrix will be HUGE: it will take at least **32 GB of RAM** for a dense matrix. 16 GB for only the upper part (with compaction) and maybe a bit less if there are a lot of 0 and you use a sparse matrix (which is probably not the case). Do you use a machine with at least 64 GB of RAM ?